# Background Color Overflowing from Parent

Tags: html, css

Im having an issue where my background color for a child element is going past my parent elements borders. How could I remedy this?

```css
.package {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.banner {}

.fedex {
  background-color: #4D148C;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6600;
}

.logo {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="package">
  <div class="banner fedex">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I should mention I tried adding the same border radius only to the top of `banner` but this then left a small gap of white space between the color and the border of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

`overflow:hidden` will prevent the inner child elements from extending beyond the bounds of the parent.

```css
.package {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.banner {}

.fedex {
  background-color: #4D148C;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6600;
}

.logo {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="package">
  <div class="banner fedex">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using `overflow: hidden`, it's also possible to use `contain: content`, which tells other elements that the child elements inside that particular element will never affect other elements, and will also never be displayed outside the parent element.

```css
.package {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;

  /* ADDED */
  contain: content;
}

.banner {}

.fedex {
  background-color: #4D148C;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6600;
}

.logo {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="package">
  <div class="banner fedex">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```